# При создании контрагента создать Расчетный счет

Tags: мойсклад-api

Я так понял, что после создания контрагента придет ответ с `id` и мета.

Но как создать по этим данным Расчетный счет?
В документации не описано. Желателно пример JSON.

Answer (score 0):

В документации [описано](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-put) как обновить Контрагента, добавив ему Расчетный счет. 
Пример:

```
   curl -X PUT \
  'http://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/counterparty/{тут id контрагенты, который получили}?expand=accounts' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic токен' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: другой токен' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "name": "test",
    "accounts": [
        {
            "accountNumber": "123123",
            "bankName":"123",
            "bic": "765432"
        }
    ]
}'
```